# How to avoid DOM dependencies in React components?

Tags: reactjs

I have a dropdown like component. On click of the dropdown, it opens up. When the user clicks anywhere else on the document, the dropdown closes. My component has two DOM dependencies:

a) It uses `document.addEventListener` to hook the click event.

b) In the `onClick` handler it compares `event.target` with its own DOM node like this:

```
const me = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
const isMyChild = $(event.target).parents().filter((i, el) => el === me).length === 1;

if( isMyChild ) {
  //don't close
  return;
} else {
  close();
}
```

How do I do this "the React way" in order to remove (or minimize) the dependencies on the DOM?